# Convert single file to Swift 3 in Xcode 8?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Is there any way in `Xcode 8` or `8.1` to do a `Swift 2.X -> Swift 3` migration for a **single file** in a project that's already been converted to Swift 3?

For technical debt/legacy build process reasons, we are currently having to maintain both `Xcode 7` and `Xcode 8` versions of our project. This is causing headaches when we have to merge new development from `Xcode 7` over to `Xcode 8`. Since the project has already been fully converted to `Swift 3` in our `Xcode 8` branch (including a ton of hand fixes), we can't use the full-project automated converter. Therefore we are currently having to do a hand conversion from `Swift 2.2` to `Swift 3` for any new `Swift` files which were added in `Xcode 7`, which takes a significant amount of time.

I apologize if this has already been asked, I couldn't find any clear answer with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a project with multiple targets where each target is a slightly more advanced version of using OpenGL with Swift. It's one project with multiple tutorials, if you will. When swift 3 became available, I used the converter, and noticed it works on a **per target basis**. With that in mind I suggest:

1. Create a dumb target in the project.
2. Add any files you want updated to this target.
3. Run the conversation editor
4. Associate or place those files back into your already converted target.

I realize it's a bit of a hack, but if it works, why not? Hope that helps.

As a side note, if you have any code dealing with `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer` and you utilize `alloc()` or `malloc(),` the converter does not replace the `alloc()`/`malloc()` with the new `UnsafeMutablePointer` methods--`allocate()` and `initialize()`.  You are likely using these if you are working with any of the C API's.

Comment: For those who down-voted, may I ask why? This is a viable answer.

Comment: Agreed, while not ideal,  right now it seems like the best approach.

Comment: @Buggy Downvoted because it didn't work and the new target got messy.

Comment: @bearacuda13 just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "the new target got messy"?  Did you get overloaded with errors saying missing definitions, or ?? Also, I'm sorry the process didn't work for you as it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: @Buggy I actually take back the target thing, it was giving me errors at first but then I just cleaned the project and it was fine. I'm using Xcode 10 now, if that makes a difference in the functionality

Comment: @bearacuda13, got it.  Glad the errors cleaned up.  Not sure if there is a difference when it comes to Xcode 10.  I'm currently still working off of 9.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

A thought (untested) is to delete the lines

```
LastSwiftMigration = 0800;
```

and/or

```
SWIFT_VERSION = 3.0;
```

from `project.pbxproj` and see if Xcode allows you to use the migrator again. Those lines were both added after I ran the migrator.

Then if it works, obviously, you need to deselect all the files you don't want migrated.

That's all I can think of anyway.