# Using Swift 3 Library in Swift 2 Project

Tags: ios, swift

So I have this library that I really need to integrate into my iOS application yet it is only available in Swift 3. My project is written in Swift 2.3 and is extremely large and will need a huge amount of time to switch into Swift 3. There is no time to do the conversion because there is a deadline to this project. Anyhow, is there any way I can use that library?

Comment: Is the library a cocoapod?

Comment: yes it is. https://cocoapods.org/?q=NextLevel

Comment: The only way is use Swift 2 branch / version if available.

Comment: This probably won't do it - but since I was seriously dinged by my answer of "no" in this thread [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362696/convert-single-file-to-swift-3-in-xcode-8/40364339#40364339 you might want to read through it. (I still stick with the consensus here - just upgrade. You will have to do it someday anyways.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not** possible to mix Swift 2.x and Swift 3.x in any circumstances.

As [NextLevel](https://github.com/nextlevel/NextLevel) has no support for Swift 2.x, you should consider spending 1 day to migrate from Swift 2.3 to 3.0.

And note that:

- Xcode provides a tool for automatic conversion from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0.
- if the project is big, you must have experienced developers with you, and it doesn't take more than a day for experienced devs to fix what remaining errors, like replacing some `AnyObject` to `Any`.
- Stackoverflow is here to help for your migration issues.
- Xcode 8.2 is the last version of Xcode supporting Swift 2.3. Xcode 8.3 will be supporting Swift 3.1 exclusively.